# How can I select n rows preceding an index row in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` and am trying to select a row (given a particular index) and the `n` rows preceding it.

I've tried something like:

```
last_10 = self.market_data.iloc[index:-10]
```

But this appears to give everything from the `index` up until the end of the dataframe minus 10 rows.

What I'd like to happen is to return the row specified by `index` and the 10 rows preceding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If general index like `DatetimeIndex` use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `val`:

```
print (market_data)
            val
Date           
1900-01-01  2.0
1900-01-02  3.0
1900-01-03  5.1
1900-01-04  5.0
1900-01-05  6.0
1900-01-06  7.0
1900-01-07  3.0

n = 3
val = '1900-01-04'
pos = market_data.index.get_loc(val)
last_10 = market_data.iloc[pos-n+1:pos+1]
print (last_10)
            val
Date           
1900-01-02  3.0
1900-01-03  5.1
1900-01-04  5.0
```

If `RangeIndex` - get 3 values before index `4` use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (market_data)
         Date  val
0  1900-01-01  2.0
1  1900-01-02  3.0
2  1900-01-03  5.1
3  1900-01-04  5.0
4  1900-01-05  6.0
5  1900-01-06  7.0
6  1900-01-07  3.0

n = 3
val = 4
last_10 = market_data.loc[val-n+1:val]
print (last_10)
         Date  val
2  1900-01-03  5.1
3  1900-01-04  5.0
4  1900-01-05  6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
n = 10
last_10 = self.market_data.iloc[index-n:index+1]
```

When slicing arrays, Python returns everything up until the last index, so you need to add one to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that te most generic way is by searching up to the index, and then search the last 10 of the previous search:

just:

```
self.market_data.loc[:index].iloc[-10]
```

that because your index could be a timestamp.